# Unable to instantiate application com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap.app.HybridApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: salesforce

I m trying to develop salesforce hybrid_local app.
My cordova version@5.4.1
eclipse ADT 23.0.2
When ever i run my app in android device getting crashed.

```
Exception:03-14 17:39:19.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1236): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
instantiate application com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap.app.HybridApp: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap.app.HybridApp
va.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap.app.HybridApp" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test-8.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.test-8, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Comment: BrettMN provided a response to my question, and it worked in my case. Pasting it here so that it helps anyone looking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47321706/exception-java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-application-com-sal/47322339#47322339