# Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap.app.HybridApp

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, salesforce-ios-sdk

I developed a hybrid mobile app integrating SalesForce Mobile SDK with Ionic using Brett Nelson's set of blog posts -

1. After following the set of instructions in this post - 
   https://wipdeveloper.com/2017/06/27/saleforce-mobile-sdk-ionic-setup-mobile-sdk/
   and setting up the org and running the app in Android Studio -> emulator, the app opened up alright.
2. After following these set of instructions - 
   https://wipdeveloper.com/author/brettmn/page/6/

wherein I integrated (basically copy pasted) - package.json elements, resources etc. - from the CLI generated Ionic app to the SalesForce SDK project in Step 1, I cannot get to run the project in emulator.

While running, the LogCat emits the following information:

*0-4310/com.wipdeveloper.contacts E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.wipdeveloper.contacts, PID: 4310
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap.app.HybridApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap.app.HybridApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.wipdeveloper.contacts-gVdyqj5Na6koBXGU6VuxfA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wipdeveloper.contacts-gVdyqj5Na6koBXGU6VuxfA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wipdeveloper.contacts-gVdyqj5Na6koBXGU6VuxfA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wipdeveloper.contacts-gVdyqj5Na6koBXGU6VuxfA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wipdeveloper.contacts-gVdyqj5Na6koBXGU6VuxfA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wipdeveloper.contacts-gVdyqj5Na6koBXGU6VuxfA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wipdeveloper.contacts-gVdyqj5Na6koBXGU6VuxfA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wipdeveloper.contacts-gVdyqj5Na6koBXGU6VuxfA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wipdeveloper.contacts-gVdyqj5Na6koBXGU6VuxfA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wipdeveloper.contacts-gVdyqj5Na6koBXGU6VuxfA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wipdeveloper.contacts-gVdyqj5Na6koBXGU6VuxfA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wipdeveloper.contacts-gVdyqj5Na6koBXGU6VuxfA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.wipdeveloper.contacts-gVdyqj5Na6koBXGU6VuxfA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                                             at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:989)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5715)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)*

---

The manifest file looks like this ->
[image]

The project structure is as below ->

[image]

What is the configuration that is missing? Or incorrect?

Note: This question here seems to have a similar problem, but no resolution:
[Unable to instantiate application com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap.app.HybridApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987653/unable-to-instantiate-application-com-salesforce-androidsdk-phonegap-app-hybrida)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After step 2 in your question, you may have to remove and then re-add the platform you are targeting.

**For iOS**

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios
ionic cordova platform add ios@4.4.0
```

**Or for Android**

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android@6.2.3
```

If you do that and still have problems try removing and re-adding the salesforce mobile sdk.

```
cordova plugin remove com.salesforce
cordova plugin add https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin --force
```